# AWS CLI list all load balancers and their associated private/public IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

As simple as it sounds, I am trying to get a list of all my load balancers (network, application, classic, gateways). Haven't been able to get the exact command to get that output from the aws cli.

Comment: The IP addresses are subject to change. The only static IP addresses for load balancers are the Elastic IPs you attach to Network Load Balancers. That's why they aren't returned from AWS CLI calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `load-balancer-id`s with [`describe-load-balancers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html) and then use [`describe-network-interfaces`](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-IP/) to get IPs:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=description,Values="ELB elb-name" --query 'NetworkInterfaces[*].PrivateIpAddresses[*].PrivateIpAddress' --output text
```

Comment: That doesn't return the IP addresses.

Comment: Good point!  Updated the answer to add describe-network-interfaces.